# Table ended with empty list as apposed to produce a list of solution

Tags: equation-solving

When I solve the following expression It produces the corresponding output.

```
H = 2*10^-11; 

KK = 1.17*10^-6;

RC = 200;

h = (H/KK);

val = (αn*RC)*BesselJ[1, αn*RC] - (h*RC)*BesselJ[0, αn*RC];

roots = Solve[val == 0 && 0 < αn < 1, αn][[All, 1, 2]]
```

But when I evaluate the same expression in Table it does not produce expected output rather ended with empty list.

```
Clear[H, A0]; 

 h = (H/KK)

 val = (αn*RC)*BesselJ[1, αn*RC] - (h*RC)*
   BesselJ[0, αn*RC]

roots = Table[
  Solve[val == 0 && 0 < αn < 1, αn], {H, 0.1*10^-11, 
   0.01*10^-11, 10*10^-11}]
```

Waiting for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Okkes Duglgerci, Thanks for your comment. I did, the way as you suggested but again it ended with the same empty list. I m not very good in Mathematica but  its not the case that table evaluate the given expression from all the values given in input list like in this case 'H'. If that's how it goes then table will automatically update 'h' in the 'val' expression and there is no need to define it inside the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look how Table is defined.

```
Table[expr,{i,imin,imax,di}]
```

where di is the step size.

Your imax is 0.01*10^-11, which is smaller than imin. Then you only get results, if di would be negative, which is not the case here.

But I think, you simply confused imax and di.

```
roots = Table[
  Solve[val == 0 && 0 < \[Alpha]n < 1, \[Alpha]n], {H, 0.1*10^-11, 
     10*10^-11, 0.01*10^-11}]
```

works, but you get a imense amount of solutions.

Comment: Thank You, Akku14.